# Installing Apache on a mac (Lion) : "Did not find prce-config script at" error

Tags: macos, apache, osx-lion

I am trying to install Apache (by compilation)on my mac Lion.

Every time, I try to compile pcre, I get these two errors :

configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/

or

"Did not find prce-config script at"

I know I have this pcre-config file.

(I put http-2.4.1 and pcre-8.30 in Documents / Tried another location in MyUsername/Test/ >> same result >> it didn't work either).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit :**

I copied http-2.4.1 and pcre-8.30 in "/" 
then I cded to /pcre-8.30

then I issued ./configure >> Got no error.

then I cded /http-2.4.1

then I issued ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache_2.2. --with-pcre=/pcre-8.30

Got 1 error configure: error: Did not find pcre-config script at /pcre-8.30

I do not understand what  "Install prefix .................. : /usr/local" means (in the pcre-8.30 configuration summary). I can't see any pcre file in this directory.

Comment: Does it work, if you put the location to the root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got apache 2.4.1 to configure by doing the following (note i am running lion v 10.7.3)

1. I downloaded pcre and ran (Note: by default pcre will install into /usr/local)

   ```
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ make install
   ```
2. setup httpd-2.4.1 with the following command

   ```
    $./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pcre=/usr/local
    $ make
    $ make install
   ```
3. Test

   ```
    $ usr/local/bin/apachectl start
   ```

This appeared to work for me hopefully it works for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Will try it asap ! Hope it will work ;-)

Comment: I needed a c++ compiler before I could install pcre. `yum gcc-c++` will install it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install Homebrew from [http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/](https://brew.sh), and then

```
brew install pcre
```

It does not need root access.

And then run the `./configure`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you not install PCRE correctly. Please try this:

Install PCRE
Nginx requires PCRE – Perl Compatible Regular Expressions to build, I used PCRE version 8.13. In a Terminal, run:

```
sudo curl -OL h ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.13.tar.gz > /usr/local/src/pcre-8.13.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src
tar xvzf pcre-8.13.tar.gz
cd pcre-8.13
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

That is what I am trying...

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't get it to work using jfleong's answer. I came across fink, which you can download here http://www.finkproject.org/download/srcdist.php

After it was all installed, I ran:

```
$ fink install pcre
```

And then continued with installing apache and just using

```
$ ./configure
```

Without any flags. After I did all of that it finally was able to finish installing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I will try this only and only if jfleong's answer doesn't work ... I am not a huge fan of macports or fink because I am more inclined to use homebrew and I have been reading that having more than one packet manager is not highly recommended. But thanks anyway.